# Why is my Bluetooth not pairing?

Tags: bluetooth

I have installed elementary OS  Hera

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 5.1.4 Hera
Release:    5.1.4
Codename:   hera

Bluetooth is not eligible to pair any device as well as its not searching so many devices. I tried everything to resolve as well as blueman app but nothing helped.

Comment: i have also tried live version it has the same isse. it is showing bluetooth and drivers installed however it has same connectivity issue.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have the best luck pairing using the command line tool bluetoothctl. I run linux mint though so things might be a little different.

Advantages to using the command line for bluetooth in linux are:

- more control over the pairing process
- error messages that are more understandable
- an easier time pairing some devices.

You may have already tried this but I figured it was worth adding to help future users with problems similar to ones that I have had who may stumble on this thread.